# How does React.createContext create multiple instances from a singe context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider my example:

```js
const itemStructure = {
  a: [ "d", "c" ],
  b: [ "e", "f" ]
};

const Context = React.createContext({
  setId: () => {}, getId: null, providerId: null
});

const InnerItem = ({ id }) => {
  const value = React.useContext(Context);
  const setItem = () => value.setId(id);

  console.log(value);

  return <button onClick={setItem}>{id}</button>;
};

const OuterItem = ({ providerId }) => {
  const [ getId, setId ] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ getId, setId, providerId }}>
      {itemStructure[providerId].map(id => <InnerItem id={id} key={id} />)}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return Object.keys(itemStructure).map(id => (
    <OuterItem providerId={id} key={id} />
  ));
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

See what the console logs after each button click as providerId. It logs the right values, but I can't understand why. I'd expect that it doesn't work as no matter which OuterItem uses it, it will be the same Context, and they share on it.

So my question is how multiple components can share on the same context, but make it identical by the Provider?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you call the `createContext`, you aren't create a instance, you only create a new type of context.

So when you call `<TypeContext>.Provider` you are creating a instance to all components are inside this context instance of this type. So whatever component that use this context, ever find the context type more near.

So some examples:

```
const OneTypeContext = React.createContext('hello world')
```

```
const WorldOne = () => {
  const value = useContext(OneTypeContext)

  console.log(value)
}
```

```
<OneTypeContext.Provider>
  <WorldOne />
</OneTypeContext.Provider>

// console.log(value) => `hello world`
```

But if you put the same context type as new instance inside other instance of same context, the function like `useContext` will find the context nearly. Ex:

```
<OneTypeContext.Provider>
  <OneTypeContext.Provider value="Hello Other World">
    <WorldOne />
  </OneTypeContext.Provider>
</OneTypeContext.Provider>

// console.log(value) => `Hello Other World`
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#api